# Defining type of TypeProvider

Tags: syntax, f#, type-providers

I am beginning to create my own Type Provider in F# but I fear a combination of poor documentation and personal inexperience (especially with the syntax) with F# is causing me trouble.

I am getting compiler errors stating that I need to declare members for my type. This leads me to believe I have some simple whitespace issues (Despite mimicking code on the MSDN webpage...)

My simple attempt at defining a Type:

```
type PoorlyWrittenQuestion =
    member briefIntro : string
    member poorDescription : string
    member confusingExample : string
```

I'm sure there are several problems here.  Extra thanks for anyone that can not only correct these problems but also point me to a reliable source of documentation for F# 3.0 syntax.

Edit: This question may need a better title, as while this is the first step in my work on a TypeProvider, I don't think my problem is TypeProvider specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to define class with non-static members than members name should start with some identifier indicating 'this' like:

```
member this.briefInfo
```

or

```
member x.briefInfo
```

(you can choose whatever id you want)
or

```
static member briefInfo
```

if you want static class member.

Here is quick guide on OOP in F#: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timng/archive/2010/04/05/f-object-oriented-programming-quick-guide.aspx

Here is tutorial on how to create Type Providers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361034.aspx

Here is another tutorial:
http://blog.mavnn.co.uk/type-providers-from-the-ground-up/